# Integrality of $(n^2)!/(n!)^{n+1}$ via Legendre's formula

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, inequality, prime-numbers, divisibility

By [combinatorial argument](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1683341/748964), it is not difficult to show that $K_n$ defined as follows is always an integer for $n\in\mathbb Z^+$:

$$
K_n={(n^2)!\over(n!)^{n+1}}
$$

Seeking alternative approach, I considered applying Legendre's formula. Let $\nu_p(N)$ denotes the largest integer such that $p^{\nu_p(N)}|N$, so we have

$$
\nu_p(K_n)=\sum_{r\ge1}\left(\left\lfloor n^2\over p^r\right\rfloor-(n+1)\left\lfloor n\over p^r\right\rfloor\right)
$$

To handle the floor function, I set $m=\nu_p(n)$ and $u=\lfloor\log n/\log p\rfloor\ge m$ so that

\begin{aligned}
\nu_p(K_n)
&=\sum_{m<r\le2m}{n^2\over p^r}-\sum_{r\le m}{n\over p^r}-\sum_{r>m}(n+1)\left\lfloor n\over p^r\right\rfloor \\
&\ge\sum_{r\le m}{n^2p^{-m}-n\over p^r}-n(n+1)\sum_{m<r\le u}p^{-r} \\
&=\sum_{r\le m}{n^2p^{-m}-n\over p^r}-p^{-m}n(n+1){1-p^{-u}\over p-1} \\
&=(n^2p^{-m}-n){1-p^{-m}\over p-1}-p^{-m}n(n+1){1-p^{-u}\over p-1} \\
&={(n^2p^{-m}-n-n^2p^{-2m}+np^{-m})-(n^2p^{-m}+np^{-m}-n^2p^{-m-u}-np^{-m-u})\over p-1} \\
&={n^2(p^{-m-u}-p^{-2m})+n(p^{-m-u}-1))\over p-1}<0
\end{aligned}

I wonder whether it is possible to improve the inequalities so that I can prove that $K_n$ is an integer.

Comment: More generally: $$\frac{(ab)!}{(a!)^bb!}$$ is an integer.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Indeed, another combinatorial corollary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is another version of Legendre's formula, given as:
$\nu_p(n!) = \frac 1{p - 1}(n - s_p(n))$, where $s_p(n)$ denotes the sum of digits of $n$ written in base $p$. It is easy to deduce this version from the version that you used.

We can easily prove that:

- $s_p(n) \leq n$;
- $s_p(n^2) \leq s_p(n)^2$. To see this, first write $n$ in base $p$ as $n = (a_r \cdots a_0)_p$, then perform the usual [long multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplication_algorithm#Long_multiplication) of $n \times n$ without carry. The result will have sum of digits equal to $s(n)^2$. After doing carry, the sum of digits can only decrease.

Thus we get \begin{eqnarray}n^2 - s_p(n^2) &\geq& n^2 - s_p(n)^2\\ &=& n^2 - 1 - (s_p(n) - 1)(s_p(n) + 1)\\ &\geq& n^2 - 1 - (s_p(n) - 1)(n + 1)\\ &=& (n + 1)(n - s_p(n))\end{eqnarray} which gives $\nu_p((n^2)!) \geq (n + 1)\nu_p(n!)$.

Comment: Thanks for answering! This variant of Legendre's formula is just brilliant!